# Is it possible to add attributes to a vector layer from csv table based on class name?

Tags: grass-gis, csv, classification

I have a vector for the region of interest, where each polygon has a class value. Also I have a classification table there each row contains a class name and class parameters in other columns. I want to add these parameters to my vector as attributes, based on the class value.
I know how to perform this with PCRaster. Is it possible with GRASS commands?
Seems that .db. commands always require coordinates, so I can't import a csv table as a simple table.
I don't have pandas and python at all on given docker container and I don't want to install it there. So is it possible using only grass commands and bash? (gdal if it could help of course ))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's certainly possible. You use the `db.in.ogr` module to get your CSV into the GRASS database, then `v.db.join` to connect between the vector table and the imported CSV table. Here's an example using the builtin North Carolina LOCATION. I use the *zipcodes_wake* vector, and I created a fictitious CSV table of string values, one for each item in the ZIPNAME column. This CSV has a new column "DESCRIP" with (ficticious) class parameters to be added to the zipcodes vector.

Here's how the CSV looks:

```
GRASS nc_spm_08_grass7/PERMANENT:~ > head class_descrip.csv 
"ZIPNAME","DESCRIP"
"CREEDMOOR","fi"
"YOUNGSVILLE","oz"
"RALEIGH","fv"
"YOUNGSVILLE","ta"
"DURHAM","jd"
....
```

I made a copy of the *zipcode_wake* vector for this example, and run these commands:

```
GRASS nc_spm_08_grass7/PERMANENT:~ > g.copy vect=zipcodes_wake,zipcodes_descripts --o
Copying vector <zipcodes_wake@PERMANENT> to current mapset as    <zipcodes_descripts>
# Import CSV
GRASS nc_spm_08_grass7/PERMANENT:~ > db.in.ogr input=class_descrip.csv output=descripts --o
Imported table <descripts> with 44 rows
# Now do the join
v.db.join map=zipcodes_descripts column=ZIPNAME other_table=descripts other_column=ZIPNAME
# Show result
GRASS nc_spm_08_grass7/PERMANENT:~ > v.db.select zipcodes_descripts column=ZIPNAME,DESCRIP
ZIPNAME|DESCRIP
CREEDMOOR|fi
YOUNGSVILLE|oz
RALEIGH|fv
YOUNGSVILLE|oz
DURHAM|jd
RALEIGH|fv
RALEIGH|fv
WENDELL|bx
RALEIGH|fv
....
```

HTH